# How does Unity decide the icon background colours?

Tags: 10.10, unity

The icons on the Unity launcher are square and contain the icon image and have a coloured background. The icons have different colours as their backgrounds (see screenshot). How does Unity decide what colour this should be?

[image: Unity Launcher]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's using the average (RGB) of the colors of the icon.

Take a look at the [upstream code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/annotate/head%3A/unity/icon-postprocessor.vala#L196) for details.

Comment: So, what happens if the icon is monochrome?  ;)

Comment: Well, the average of one white pixel and one black pixel is 50% neutral grey (127, 127, 127). ;-) And transparent pixels seem to count as black.